# Merge [chromecast] and [google-cast-sdk] into [google-cast]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

We have [google-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cast) and it is a sponsored tag. There are also [chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromecast) and [google-cast-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cast-sdk). We should synonymise these two into [google-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cast).